# adding a sudoer in debian

Tags: debian, sudo, users, root, su

After a long search on the web, trying everything I can find I came to ask you guys, how can I add an existing user to be a sudoer?

I've tried

```
usermod -a -G sudo user
```

and also

```
adduser user
```

both while in root...
the first one didn't work at all and the second one supposedly added 'user' to sudoers but when I try to run sudo with that user it says:
user is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.

When I run adduser again, it says the user 'user' is already a member of 'sudo'.

what can I do???

-EDIT: for clarification, I do want the user to be prompted for a password when trying to run sudo. currently when the user is running sudo he is being prompted for a password and then he gets "user is not in sudoers file...."
I wand him to be able to run sudo, be prompted and then escalate the privilege.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As root edit /etc/sudoers and place the following line:

```
youruser    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

after

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

In this way you will be capable to execute all commands that require sudo privileges passwordless.

In order to use sudo and be prompted for a password you need to remove

```
NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: where should I place the youruser ALL line? the %sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL is already there

Comment: after the line:
"%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL"

You should replace "youruser" with your username in the example.

Comment: but I do want the user to be prompted for a password

Comment: use the following code:
youruser    ALL=(ALL) ALL

Comment: If there is an (syntax) error in Your `/etc/sudoers` you may loose your sudo access at all.- Use `visudo` instead.

Answer (score 16):

Following command is correct and enough but you **need to completely logout the user and relogin** to work .

```
usermod -a -G sudo user
```

Comment: I've found that logging out and logging in again often isn't enough, but a full restart is required.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, in Debian if it doesn't work you need to install sudo package:

```
apt install sudo
```

Then you should have `/etc/sudoers` file and proceed as follows:

```
usermod -a -G sudo user
```

Comment: If you've already manually created `/etc/sudoers`, an interactive prompt will ask you if you'd like to replace it with the default installed from Apt.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the following command as **root**: (where `USERNAME` is replaced with your actual username)

```
usermod -aG sudo USERNAME
```

It won't work if you try to run this command under an unprivileged user.
So to gain root rights and to make sure that the necessary packages are installed, do this:

```
su
[enter password for your root user]
apt update
apt upgrade
apt install sudo
apt install usermod
usermod -ag sudo USERNAME
reboot
```

Don't forget to reboot at the end!
After the reboot the user should be able to use `sudo` commands.

**Tip:** if you tried to run a long command which failed because it actually requires sudoer rights, you can use the following trick to run the command again but this time with the correct privilege:

```
sudo !!
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/sudo/)

```
Add existing user from commandline  

To add an existing user with id=foo to group=sudo:
```

> $ sudo adduser foo sudo

Alternatively, you can first get root (e.g., sudo su -) and then run the same commands without prefix=sudo:

> ```
> # adduser foo
> # adduser foo sudo
> ```
>
> After being added to a new group the user must log out and then log back in again for the new group to take effect. Groups are only
> assigned to users at login time. A most common source of confusion is
> that people add themselves to a new group but then do not log out and
> back in again and then have problems because the group is not
> assigned; be sure to verify group membership.